# Query to generate string based on values in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in database that has structure and data as follows:

```
+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  ID |  Col1  |  Col2  |  Col3  |  Col4  |  Col5  |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1  |  MALE  |  MALE  | FEMALE |  NULL  |  NULL  |
|  2  | FEMALE |  MALE  |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  |
|  3  | FEMALE |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  |
|  4  |  MALE  | OTHER  | FEMALE | FEMALE |  NULL  |
|  5  |  MALE  | OTHER  | FEMALE |  MALE  | FEMALE |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

The order of data has to be in order of first appearance in the columns, from `Col1` to `Col5`, to get the following output:

```
+-----+--------------------------------------------+
|  ID | Remarks                                    |
+-----+--------------------------------------------+
|  1  | 2 Male and 1 Female                        |
|  2  | 1 Female and 1 Male                        |
|  3  | 1 Female                                   |
|  4  | 1 Male, 1 Other and 2 Female               |
|  5  | 2 Male, 1 Other and 2 Female               |
+-----+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The table structure will make queries complicated. Do you need to keep the structure?

Comment: Seconding the above comment, why is the source table structured like this?

Comment: If you had a row with the following data MALE, OTHER, FEMALE, MALE, NULL would you expect to see "1 Male, 1 Other, 1 Female and 1 Male" or "2 Male, 1 Other and 1 Female"? Either could be a valid response to the data shown.

Comment: Also, how important is the order of the output? Would you be just as happy if the first row said "1 Female and 2 Male"? How about "2 Male, 1 Female" (no "and")

Comment: @user2652379.. It's a legacy system and hence the structure. We are in process of normalising the tables but till then we have to fulfill the reporting requirements.

Comment: @DancingFool, there order of data has to be in order of column. For e.g., if Col1 has MALE, Col2 has OTHER, Col3 has FEMALE, Col4 has MALE and Col5 has FEMALE then the remarks should be "2 Male, 1 Other and 2 Female".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very unusual requirement and I would imagine that you don't *really* need to have the values in the order you are asking for, but to answer the question as asked:

```
-- Build data
declare @t table(ID int,Col1 varchar(10),Col2 varchar(10),Col3 varchar(10),Col4 varchar(10),Col5 varchar(10));
insert into @t values
 (1,'MALE','MALE','FEMALE',null,null)
,(2,'FEMALE','MALE',null,null,null)
,(3,'FEMALE',null,null,null,null)
,(4,'MALE','OTHER','FEMALE','FEMALE',null)
,(5,'MALE','OTHER','FEMALE','MALE','FEMALE')
;

-- Query
with d as
(   -- Manually unpivot the 5 Cols and add a row number
    select 1 as r
            ,ID
            ,Col1 as Col
    from @t
    union all
    select 2
            ,ID
            ,Col2 as Col
    from @t
    union all
    select 3
            ,ID
            ,Col3 as Col
    from @t
    union all
    select 4
            ,ID
            ,Col4 as Col
    from @t
    union all
    select 5
            ,ID
            ,Col5 as Col
    from @t
)
,c as
(   -- Replace Col values for presentation and add in aggregated row numbers, ranks and counts for each value
    select ID
            ,case Col when 'MALE' then 'Male'
                        when 'FEMALE' then 'Female'
                        when 'OTHER' then 'Other'
                        end as Col
            ,row_number() over (partition by ID order by r) as rn
            ,dense_rank() over (partition by ID order by r) as drk
            ,rank() over (partition by ID, Col order by r) as rk
            ,count(Col) over (partition by ID, Col) as c
    from d
    where Col is not null
)
,o as
(   -- Filter rows down to just the first instance of that Col value to get the presentation order
    select ID
            ,row_number() over (partition by ID order by rn) as o
            ,cast(c as varchar(10)) + ' ' + Col as c
    from c
    where rk = 1
)
    -- Collate the data per presentation rules
select o.ID
        ,o.c
         + isnull(case when o3.ID is null
                    then ' and ' + o2.c
                    else ', ' + o2.c + ' and ' + o3.c
                    end
                    ,'') as Remarks
from o
    left join o as o2
        on o.ID = o2.ID
            and o2.o = 2
    left join o as o3
        on o.ID = o3.ID
            and o3.o = 3
where o.o = 1
order by o.ID;
```

Output:

```
+----+------------------------------+
| ID |           Remarks            |
+----+------------------------------+
|  1 | 2 Male and 1 Female          |
|  2 | 1 Female and 1 Male          |
|  3 | 1 Female                     |
|  4 | 1 Male, 1 Other and 2 Female |
|  5 | 2 Male, 1 Other and 2 Female |
+----+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this use `apply`.

```
select t.*,
       (case when num_male = 0 and num_female = 0 and num_other = 0
             then ''
             when num_male = 0 and num_female = 0
             then replace('num_other OTHER', 'num_other', num_other)
             when num_male = 0 and num_other = 0
             then replace('num_female FEMALE', 'num_female', num_female)
             when num_male = 0 and num_female = 0
             then replace('num_male MALE', 'num_male', num_male)
             when num_male = 0 
             then replace(replace(replace('num_other OTHER AND num_female FEMALE'), 'num_male', num_male), 'num_other', num_other), 'num_female', num_female)
             when num_other = 0 
             then replace(replace(replace('num_male MALE AND num_female FEMALE), 'num_male', num_male), 'num_other', num_other), 'num_female', num_female)
             when num_female = 0 
             then replace(replace(replace('num_male MALE AND num_other OTHER), 'num_male', num_male), 'num_other', num_other), 'num_female', num_female)
             else replace(replace(replace('num_male MALE, num_other OTHER AND num_female FEMALE), 'num_male', num_male), 'num_other', num_other), 'num_female', num_female)
        end) as remarks
from t cross apply
     (select sum(case when col = 'FEMALE' then 1 else 0 end) as num_females,
             sum(case when col = 'MALE' then 1 else 0 end) as num_males,
             sum(case when col = 'OTHER' then 1 else 0 end) as num_other
      from (values (col1), (col2), (col3), (col4), (col5)) v(col)
     ) v;
```

I don't see an advantage to cleverness in calculating the remarks structure.

Comment: For `ID = 2` the order of the `Remarks` is incorrect.  I agree that this is probably not actually important, but does mean that this doesn't fully answer the question.